# QTreeView добавить ветку

Tags: c++, qt

Как в QTreeView добавить ветку? Добавить дочернюю ветку?

Answer (score 1):

Для этого нужно в модели реализовать виртуальный метод hasChildren() , который будет возвращать true для тех элементов, у которых есть дети и false для тех, у кого их нет.

Также следует переопределить parent ( const QModelIndex & index ) , rowCount и columnCount()

Answer (score 0):

Отказался от QTreeView... Сделал через QTreeWidget:

```
// создаем новый итем (пусть сначала базовый)
QTreeWidgetItem *topLevelItem=new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->treeWidget);
// вешаем его на наше дерево в качестве топ узла.
ui->treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(topLevelItem);
// укажем текст итема
topLevelItem->setText(0,"Итем");
// создаем новый итем и сразу вешаем его на наш базовый
QTreeWidgetItem *item=new QTreeWidgetItem(topLevelItem);
// укажем текст итема
item->setText(0,"Под итем");
```